# Checkbox change value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a script that when a checkbox is clicked then it will clear an adjacent cell.

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 6) { // 6 == column F
    var columnERange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 5, eventRange.getNumRows(), 5);
    columnERange.setValues("");
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: (note that there is a `Range#offset` method that may be useful)

Comment: use `setValue()`(no s). Note that there's a `range.clearContent()` method.

Comment: I am getting an error on line 2 "Cannot read property "range" from undefined.

function onEdit(event) {
  var eventRange = event.range;
  if (eventRange.getColumn() == 6) { // 6 == column F
    var columnCRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(eventRange.getRow(), 3, eventRange.getNumRows(), 3);
    columnCRange.range.clearContent();
  }
}

Comment: I am trying to get it that when the checkbox is marked true in column F that it clears the contents in column C

Comment: `columnCRange.clearContent();`